# How can I Protect/Lock a spreadsheet but allow the use to make Validation List Selections?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, data-validation, password-protection

I would like the user to be able to select the Validation List drop-down and make a selection but if the cell is Formatted as "Locked" and "Hidden" and Protection is turned on, as soon as the selection is made the Excel Warning Message appears "The cell or chart you're trying to change is protected".

However if I deselect "Locked" in the Protection Formatting, the user can destroy the cell...drag it somewhere, put a formula in it, basically ruin the spreadsheet.

Ideally the spread sheet would be fully Protected/Locked and the only thing the user could do would be able to make a Validation List Selection and nothing else.  IMO there should be an option in the "Protect Sheet" dialog that allows you to check "Use Validation List Selections".

Any ideas?

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The steps to protect a sheet are two-fold:

1. Select the cells (one or more) that you want the user to edit. Open the formatting dialog and on the **Protection** tab untick the option **Locked**. Repeat that for every cell that you want to be editable.
2. Click Review > Protect sheet. Select the options you want and set a password or not.

Now only **unlocked** cells can be edited. If you find you need more cells to be editable, unprotect the sheet and start again with step 1 above.